# How to get remote branch and switch to it with git and vsts?

Tags: git

I have a local repo that tracks a remote repo in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and currently is in branch master. A colleague has pushed a new feature branch to the remote. I want to pull that remote and switch to it. I've tried the following:

```
git pull
git pull --all
git branch
```

does not show the new remote branch locally. I also tried

```
git checkout -b FeatureBranch origin/FeatureBranch
```

but I get this error:

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'FeatureBranch' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/FeatureBranch' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Also tried

```
git checkout --track origin/FeatureBranch
```

which I think is the same as the previous command and get the same error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
git status
```

gives

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: I know nothing about VSTS, but as far as Git itself goes, the errors you are seeing indicate that you do not have `origin/FeatureBranch` in your repository. Use `git branch -r` to see remote-tracking branch names, or `git branch -a` to see all local *and* remote-tracking branch names. I also recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely (split it into `git fetch` followed by whichever second Git command you prefer).

Comment: `git branch -r` shows remote branches; `git checkout origin/FeatureBranch` checks out a branch that exists remote but not locally.

Comment: Interesting. `git branch -r` does not show the remote branch, neither does `git branch -a`. But I can clearly see it via the VSTS web interface. I'm wondering if VSTS is broken or if there's a permissions issue somewhere.

Comment: I cloned the repo to a new directory and all the above commands worked. Not sure what's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pull` only fetches the to-be integrated remote branch. You should use `fetch` instead to update all remote tracking branches in your local repository with the brnaches from the remote. After that your command should work and `git branch -a` or `git branch -r` will show that branch. Also after it is fetched, if it is not present in multiple remotes, you can even simply do `git checkout FeatureBranch` and it will implicitly do the same as `git checkout -b FeatureBranch origin/FeatureBranch`, except you are using an ancient Git version.